# EF6 - BaseClass data duplication

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a base class `A` and derived class `B`. `B` is introduced in my latest migration. I am going for a `Table-per-Type` inheritance. There can be many `B`s for one `A`. The error I am getting when trying to `update-database` is related the Index on `A.Designation`, because the DB gets populated by the `Seed` method. I **do** understand where this error comes from, but I do not know how to avoid it.

The base class:

```
[Table("As")]
class A
{
    [Key]
    public Id { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Designation { get; set; }

    // This is mapped via EF and required by Bs constructor
    public ICollection<SomeType> SomeType { get; set; }

    // Parameter less constructor for EntityFramework
    private A() { }

    public A(string designation)
    {
        Designation = designation;
    }
}
```

The derived class:

```
[Table("Bs")]
class B : A 
{
    public B(A a) : base(a.designation)
    {
         foreach (SomeType someType in A.SomeTypes)
         {
             // Do something
         }
    }
}
```

So in the `Seed` method first an instance `a` of `A`, then an instance `b` of `B` based on `a` is added to the DB.
As I understand it, calling `new B(a)` creates a new instance of `A` which also is added to the DB which fails because of the unique index.

How do I avoid this?

I want the data to be referenced, not duplicated. I guess it would be possible to use a `Table-per-Hierarchy` scheme but that would duplicate the data of `A` for each `B`, (right?) which I would like to avoid, especially because `A.SomeEntities` would have its entries duplicated as well.

Another possibility that just popped into my mind, is passing the the Id of `a` to `b`'s constructor, but that would then have to call the `DbContext` and probably imply some other weirdness I am missing right now.

Comment: You dont have to create a A instance. Just instantiate your B class and save it in your DbContext. You'll have both A ans B tables filled

Comment: @Béranger but the A instance should be there on its own. There can and will be multiple instances of B that get constructed from this A instance.

Comment: I think your A object should be a property of B. B shouldnt inherit from A

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll do it that way... But I don't quite like it because in my actual classes (not the simplified ones here) this leads to quite some code duplication and I cannot assign a B instance to an A variable which also would have been handy for my use case.

Comment: What about use an interface to define common behaviour and use extension methods to avoid duplicate code?

Comment: Yes, as I implemented a separate test project with the same structure to play around, I'll came to the same conclusion. Another way could be to use a not inheriting mapping type to map to an actually inheriting (but not tracked by EF) wrapper class, but I think in my case the inheritance isn't worth the extra effort and complexity, since similar enough behavior can be achieved with an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to link with existing object instead of class inheritance?

Why not create a link between your b and a?

```
   [Table("Bs")]
    class B
    {
public A referredA {get;set;}
        public B(A a) 
        {
           referredA=a;
        }
    }
```